# setImage not working on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewCell` with an `imageview` that acts as a "`checkbox`" where when clicked, it will `check` or `uncheck`. I have a method for this within my `UITableViewCell`

```
-(void) toggleCheck {
    if(checked) {
        checked = NO;
        [self.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"empty-check.png"]];
    } else {
        checked = YES;
    [self.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"check.png"]];
    }
}
```

and then in my `ViewController`, I am doing this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        CheckCell *cell = (CheckCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CheckCell"];
        if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CheckCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        [cell toggleCheck]; // check the box
    }
}
```

But the UIImageView image doesn't change. I've also tried doing `[tableView reloadData]` with no luck

Any ideas on why this isn't updating?

Comment: Why do you modify `checked` inside the `toggleCheck` method?

Comment: Checked is a BOOL to keep track of whether t is checked or not

Comment: Where is imageView defined? Shouldn't it be added to cell instead of self?

Comment: did you breakpointed this part of the code to make sure its called?

Comment: Yes the 'toggleView' method IS being called

Comment: Sorry, I meant toggleCheck is being called

Comment: why don't you use button instead of an imageView and set IBAction to that button

Comment: Are you getting your cell when dequeuing your new cell?
why are you creating a new cell in didSelect?
try using `[yourtable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];` to get the cell

Comment: @TajAhmed This worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Hi @user1282637 i have posted the suggestion as answer you can mark that as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not create a new cell in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.
creating a new cell in the method is of no use.
you can get your selected cell using `[yourtable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`
*consider this code for example*

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        CheckCell *cell = (CheckCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell toggleCheck]; // check the box
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try doing it this way... because the image may not be getting set as u are accessing the `cell.imageView` outside the delegate method

also i am not sure whether u are accessing the right image. If u are using `self.imageView` u need to declare imageView as the a `@property` first.
and doing that will give u problems as u are reusing the table cells when ur number of rows in table increases.

Also writing a separate function toggle is not necessary here so u can skip it and write it in `didSelect` method

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
           CheckCell *cell = (CheckCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CheckCell"];
        if (cell == nil) 
        {
             NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CheckCell" owner:self options:nil];
             cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        if(checked) 
        {
           checked = NO;
           [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"empty-check.png"]];
        }
        else 
        {
           checked = YES;
           [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"check.png"]];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your implementation. The checked state should not be part of the UITableViewCell instance. It should be part of your model. Note that table view will reuse your cells, so maintaining the checked status in the table view cell will not work as expected. You have to store the checked state in your model and update the cell checked status using that model's property. The table view cell should be used just to draw the cell and not maintain any states because it will get reused when there are many cells in the table.